# Amazon AWS poor performance populating RDS database from EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

From an AWS newbie. Before I throw money at Amazon for higher-performing servers for my ETL tool, am I getting the most out of my existing setup?

I have set up a SQL Server RDS instance (db.m1.small) to which I'm connecting from a RHEL-6 EC2 instance (m1.small). On the EC2 I have a Python ETL job to read source flat-file data and run inserts to the RDS over the Microsoft ODBC driver. This process it an order of magnitude slower than when everything is hosted on my 64-bit Core-i7 Windows laptop with a large SSD drive.

My two servers are not in a VPC but are talking to each other via the same Internet IPs that I connect to them with from my laptop; could this be at the root of my performance problem? Could performance be improved if they were talking over local IPs instead? I've looked at Amazon's documentation of VPCs but they tout security improvements only, never performance improvements, over EC2 security groups.

Thanks for any help, BH

Comment: Within ec2, you should be using private ips. Otherwise your traffic is routed out to the edge before routed back in. CPU power wise, compared to your laptop, the small instances are quite slow.

Comment: Adding to @datasage, I would say that you should place the RDS instance and EC2 instance in the same availability zone. Take into account that m1.small instances have rather low network I/O and are backed by traditional HDDs, not SSDs. It might also prove useful to rely on ephemeral storage instances, rather than EBS, if you don't need persistence on EC2.

Comment: That being said, AWS and cloud systems in general are known for rather slow I/O. You'll see vast improvements with larger instances.

Comment: Thanks, these are very helpful comments. I had assumed my availability zones were the same, but following up from your suggestion I found out my RDS is in us-east-1d but my EC2 is in us-east-1c. I'll see if I can switch one of my availability zones so they match. Also, I had assumed incorrectly that since I was using the same public _DNS_ that it was resolving to the same public IP, but on my EC2 the public DNS is resolving to a private IP, so that resolves my suspicions about the IP.

Comment: You should be using the public DNS. It will resolve correctly outside and inside ec2.

Comment: After cloning my RDS instance to the same availability zone (us-east-1c) as my EC2, I am seeing more than double the performance.